# Is it possible to translate form language at the text drawing level?

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, drawtext, language-translation

I'm trying to make a simple method to translate my application.
I thought maybe it's possible to translate the form with a Dictionary at the text drawing level by override the Graphics class.
And even edit the drawing point same way for support RightToLeft Languages.
Someone have some good idea?

Answer (score 0):

> I thought maybe it's possible to translate the form with a Dictionary at the text drawing level by override the Graphics class.

The `Graphics` class cannot be overridden. You can override the `OnPaint` method of the controls. But how would you separate the text drawing from any other drawing? And what do you expect to get if someone reads the `Text` property, for example?

> Someone have some good idea?

Yes, use the built-in solutions for localization. Just set `Localizable` property on your form to `true`. Now you can switch languages at design time and edit everything for that language at design time, not just text but also RightToLeft property, sizes and basically everything.

When you start the application the form will use the Windows language or falls back to the invariant language. If you want to change the language programmatically just set `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` property. You might want to reopen your form to apply the language or call `InitializeComponent()` explicitly.

Comment: This is interesting way, I will check it out. And for your question, what I meant is to translate just the output to the display so the Text property will stay the original.

Comment: That would be very misleading and lacks every convention. Btw why is it a problem if the `Text` property returns the text on the control? If you need something stationary there is the `Name` property and also you can use the `Tag` for any custom purpose.

Comment: If I'm translating the Text property I can't return the original and this can cause problems in some situations (for example, ComboBox with options list), if the translating was done in the drawing time the Text property remains the source and so will be possible to change the language easily at any moment by redrawing.

Comment: Just set `Localizable` and then you can see how the generated `InitializeComponents` method changes. The `ApplyResources` (which is the built-in "translator engine") uses the `Name` property too. So in your translator dictionary the `Name` property should be the key (which is constant) and the `Text` is the value (which is mutable).